# Error registering Weather Forcast data model (NGSI v2)

Tags: fiware, fiware-orion

I am trying to register weather forcast on `ContextBroker` V1.5.0 but getting below error :-

400 Bad Request
    {
      "error": "BadRequest",
      "description": "attribute must be a JSON object, unless keyValues option is used"
    }

Request:
    POST http://[ContextBroker IP]:1026/v2/entities

Request header :
    Content-Type:application/json

Here is the payload

```
 {
    "feelsLikeTemperature":31.8,
    "dayMinimum":{"feelsLikeTemperature":31.8,"temperature":0.0,"relativeHumidity":31.0},
    "temperature":0.0,
    "dateCreated":"2016-12-01T12:05:00+05:30",
    "type":"WeatherForecast",
    "address":{"addressCountry":"IN","postalCode":"452001","addressLocality":"Indore"},
    "windSpeed":3.7,
    "validity":{"to":"2016-12-01T06:44:37Z","from":"2016-12-01T06:44:37Z"},
    "source":"http://dataservice.accuweather.com/",
    "precipitationProbability":0,
    "dayMaximum":{"feelsLikeTemperature":31.8,"temperature":0.0,"relativeHumidity":31.0},
    "weatherType":"Partly sunny",
    "windDirection":"ENE",
    "id":"452001_IN_YYYY-12-DD ",
    "relativeHumidity":31.0
}
```

I verified with `FIWARE` data models on http://fiware-datamodels.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Weather/WeatherForecast/doc/spec/index.html but it does not seem to be working. Does anyone know solution to this problem?

Comment: You have include the payload of your request in the question post. Could you edit it to include the verb + URL at least (it would be greate if you could also include the HTTP headers in the request), please? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you are using the 'keyValues' representation so you need to do your POST with ?options=keyValues

by the way the WeatherForecast data model just landed updated with some adjustments to comply with GSMA specification.

http://fiware-datamodels.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Weather/WeatherForecast/doc/spec/index.html

thanks!

Comment: It worked and thanks for updating the specification.